# Powershell script automation Visio: How to randomly more dynamic glue to another shape?

Tags: powershell, visio

I am trying to automate Visio by using powershell script.
I have a visio shape "Start" --"x shape" pointing to "BeginX" and targeting to "PosX" (therefore having a dynamic end).

I do not manage to randomly move the dynamic.

```
$begin = $connect.CellsU("BeginX").GlueToPos($shape,1);
$end = $connect.CellsU("EndX").GlueToPos($rect,0);
```

Is there a way to randomly auto move the existing connector to the end of shape?

Please and thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared these simple vba macro and gif animation for display behavior of dynamic connectors [image]

Comment: Do you have any idea on powershell script? In order to do it in visual basic  application . Please and thanks....

Answer (score 0):

CJP!

Please read more about GlueToPos method in MS Visio [Cell.GlueToPos Method (Visio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Visio-VBA/articles/cell-gluetopos-method-visio)

You need use 3 arguments (Shape,  x-coordinate,  y-coordinate) in this method !

Comment: The code works. $begin = $connect.CellsU("BeginX").GlueToPos($shape,1,5/13+0.5/13);
$end = $connect.CellsU("EndX").GlueToPos($rect,0,0/1+0.5/1);

Comment: Thanks for  your advice. However, now I wanted to make it randomly to connect the existing connector ( The photo that I posted "Output that I want") ...May I know the solutions please?  Thank you so much...

Comment: You mean dynamic connectors ?

Comment: yup. Do I need to assign variables?

Comment: Please check my answer, not a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic connector is feature based on Visio application core, which generated this connector behavior ! If open **Behavior window** for dynamic connector 
[image: Behavior window]

You can find there a lot of settings, such as **Style**, **Reroute** and **Appearance**. I did some experiments with dynamic connectors, connectors route unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks again Surrogate !

Comment: However, what if I randomly do the dynamic connectors by using powershell script?  Does it need to declare a variable? Thanks you again...